# Reshaping an array of matrices into one matrix without a for-loop

Tags: python, matrix, reshape

I want to reshape an array of matrices into a single matrix, so that if the original array has shape (n, m, N) the new matrix, X, has shape (N, nxm) and in a way so that if we look at `X[i,:].reshape(n,m)` we would get back the original i-th matrix.

This can be done with a for-loop and ravel:

```
X = np.zeros((N, n*m))
for i in range(N):
  X[i, :]=Y[:,:,i].ravel() # Y is the original array with shape (n,m,N)
print(X.shape)
```

**Question**
Is there a way to do this without using a for-loop, perhaps with just reshape and some other functions? I did not quite find this case when I tried to search online, and doing simply `X=Y.reshape((N, n*m))` does not preserve the matrix structure when we check an entry as described above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before `np.reshape`, you can use [`np.moveaxis`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.moveaxis.html) (e.g. `np.moveaixs(Y, -1, 0)`) to move the last axis of `Y` to the first and make its size to `(N, n, m)` with the matrix stucture preserved.

Comment: This worked. Thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 0):

list comprehension

`X = np.r_[[Y[:, :, i].ravel() for i in Y.shape[2]]]`

Comment: Thanks for the answer but sorry, I should have rather said neither a for-loop nor list-comprehension...